# Removing a freeze panel after validation fails on the client using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a freeze panel that pops up when a user submits a form preventing them from clicking on any other controls within the page. This works fine along with validating the form controls from the attributes set on my MVC Service controller.

The problem is when a user enters an email address with a space in-between the account name and the @ sign - someName @email.com. I receiving a small white popup box validating error message pointing at the email textbox. I'm guessing it's from jQuery because the Create controller method never fires off. The big problem is the freeze panel stays in place, so you cannot correct the problem until you refresh the page.

I'm a novice when it comes to jQuery and lost on how to correct this issue. I'm guessing that I need to identify when jQuery has fired off its validation exception for an incorrect email address, so that I can change the css property for the freeze pane back to the hidden state.

Any help would be greatly excepted!

In my model class I have this property for the email.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required")]
    [StringLength(125), EmailAddress(), Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

And in my controller I have this simple create method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ClientService clientservice)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.ClientServices.Add(clientservice);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Completed");
        }         
            return View("Create");
    }
```

My Create view I have this code that loads a partial view containing the input controls along with the freeze pane div and jQuery script controlling the panel.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   <fieldset class="user-input">
       <legend>Client Service</legend>
       <h2 class="margin-indent">How to contact -</h2><br />
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)

       <p class="margin-indent">
        <input id="pageSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
   </fieldset>
   }

   <div id="FreezePane" class="FreezePaneOff">
   <div id="InnerFreezePane" class="InnerFreezePane"> </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('#pageSubmit').click(function (event) {
    var itemErrors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (itemErrors >= 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(10);
        $('#FreezePane').toggleClass('FreezePaneOn');
        $('#InnerFreezePane').text("Processing...");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I came across this bit of code that does exactly what I needed. It captures the submit, and attaches a handler to prevent the default action on a button after the form is validated.

```
    $('form').one('submit', function (evt) {
        //unhide the freeze panel after validating form
        $('html,body').scrollTop(10);
        $('#FreezePane').toggleClass('FreezePaneOn');
        $('#InnerFreezePane').text("Processing...");
        /**
         * disable default action (this handler will be attached after first 
         * submit event and it will prevent any further submit action
         */
        $(this).on('submit', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is this -- initialize the freeze pane only after all the validations have passed and the form is submitted. This way if there is a validation error the user can still edit the field and click submit again.

This will work provided that the email verification is being done on the client that is JS. If you are not sure about that.. try finding the source of the validation pop up. You can give some more details for me figure that out.. like the fiddler trace of the entire usecase etc.

Comment: The validation is coming from jQuery but I can't see how within fiddler trace because there is nothing being recorded from submitting the form and the popup displaying. I updated the JS code for the submit trying to capture the validator.numberOfInvalids and preformed a check on the number of errors. This does prevent the freeze panel from blocking the page but it also does not show the panel after all errors are corrected.